# Jboss filter can't catch all client's HTTP requests

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, servlet-filters

I have a big problem with jboss servlet filters. I have created a filter for specific url-pattern, but the filter can't catch all requests to the pattern, only catch the OPTIONS HTTP request from client.

My filter is declared in web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>myFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>myPattern</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The problem for me is why i can't catch all request from the client...

PS. I'm using this package com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter, also filter is available in javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter.
I don't know what is the difference between them...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what the problem is:-

First of all you need to use a RequestFilter and not a ResponseFilter.

`com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilter` is a jersey 1.x filter.
[API link here.](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.6/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html)

The latest version of jersey uses `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`. [API link here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html)

Looks like you have both jersey 1.x and 2.x jars  in your classpath. You need to use the one you need and remove the other.

Assuming you are using the latest 2.x jars
You need to implement your own RequestFilter which will look like:-

```
    @Provider
    public class YourReqeustFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
         @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
                        throws IOException {
             // Use ContainerRequestContext  to intercept the http request.
           }
        }
    }
```

Then your web.xml for the servlet should look like this:-

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MY API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter</param-name>
            <param-value>yourReqeustFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilterr</param-name>
            <param-value>yourResponseFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

However please note that when your page is protected through declarative security in your web.xml and there is a filter on it; your filter wont be able to get a hold on the blocked HTTP requests on your page; due to the fact that the requests first go to your container and container protects it due to the declarative security and then the request finally comes to your filter. In short container takes precedence over your filter.

In such cases though you can separate the concerned page out of your declarative security and handle security part programatically in your filter.

For example in the above `filter` method you can get a hold on the `SecurityContext` using :-
`requestContext.getSecurityContext()` and and get access to methods that provide access to security.
A start on programmatic security [here.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=170809&seqNum=10)

Comment: I've tried with ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter and java servlet filter but still can't catch post requests from client to the server. The requests are send to protected page if this is matter...

Comment: Do you get a handle to `ContainerRequestContext` in your Request filter?

Comment: Yes, the filters can't catch my HTTP Post requests from client to the protected page in my jboss...

Comment: OK. Looks like you have enabled declarative security for that page in your web.xml. Can you separate that page out from your url pattern and check if you are able to fetch all post requests to begin with?

Comment: I've tried, but the page is protected, when i move it to the unprotected-pages there is no problem with catch HTTP post requests from client...
The question is:
Why i can't catch HTTP requests to the protected pages?

Comment: No i can't it breaks my logic...

This is my sercurity-constraint for the page

`<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Check policy security</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
   <web-resource-name>Protected pages</web-resource-name>
   <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
   <http-method>GET</http-method>
   <http-method>POST</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
   <role-name>MY_ROLE</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>`

Comment: Which servlet version is it?